# How are JWT tokens updated in cookie?

Tags: c#, angular, cookies, jwt, aspnetboilerplate

Imagine a scenario in which every time you need access to a certain part of a service (obtainable via REST API methods; e.g. access and refresh tokens), you write those tokens into JWT tokens and update cookies in your browser so that you can access those tokens from `AbpSession`.

```
private string CreateAccessToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, TimeSpan? expiration = null)
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _configuration.Issuer,
        audience: _configuration.Audience,
        claims: claims,
        notBefore: now,
        expires: now.Add(expiration ?? _configuration.Expiration),
        signingCredentials: _configuration.SigningCredentials
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
}
```

When you create the JWT token, you get an `AuthenticateResultModel` in the `Authenticate` method that is called when the user logs in.

```
public async Task<AuthenticateResultModel> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel model)
{
    // ...

    return new AuthenticateResultModel
    {
        AccessToken = accessToken,
        EncryptedAccessToken = GetEncrpyedAccessToken(accessToken),
        ExpireInSeconds = (int)_configuration.Expiration.TotalSeconds,
        UserId = (long)AbpSession.UserId
    };
}
```

If successful, the `login` method is called.

```
private login(accessToken: string, encryptedAccessToken: string, expireInSeconds: number, rememberMe?: boolean): void {

    var tokenExpireDate = rememberMe ? (new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * expireInSeconds)) : undefined;

    this._tokenService.setToken(
        accessToken,
        tokenExpireDate
    );

    this._utilsService.setCookieValue(
        AppConsts.authorization.encrptedAuthTokenName,
        encryptedAccessToken,
        tokenExpireDate,
        abp.appPath
    ); 
}
```

From my understanding, in `CreateAccessToken`, you serialize the JWT token and set cookie values in your browser via the `login` function.

Now what I wonder is, when I create another token and set cookie values, do I overwrite the previous token? Or is the previous token deleted?
I can't find any information about this topic and the reason I am asking is that I will update this token many times in the lifespan of the application, and I am worried about the storage and memory impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I create another token and set cookie values, do I overwrite the previous token? Or is the previous token deleted?

The previous token is overwritten in [`setCookieValue`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/82e72bb380e543f3c2e81a32a9be3a67af402c10/src/Abp.Web.Resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js#L701-L730):

```js
abp.utils.setCookieValue = function (key, value, expireDate, path, domain) {
    var cookieValue = encodeURIComponent(key) + '=';

    if (value) {
        cookieValue = cookieValue + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }

    // ...

    document.cookie = cookieValue;
};
```